# How to change other element when hover by using 'styled'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm new to Mui and trying to apply animation to components.

What I want to do is, I have four same component and each has its own image.

```
 <MyComponent>some images...</MyComponent>
 <MyComponent>some images...</MyComponent>
 <MyComponent>some images...</MyComponent>
 <MyComponent>some images...</MyComponent>

const MyComponent = styled("div")((theme) => ({

  //... some styles. 

  // scale up when hovered
  '&:hover': {
      transform: "scale(1.2)",
      marginRight: "20px",
   
  }
}));
```

If I hover a `<MyComponent>`,  I want to scale up hovered one, and scale down others.

Is there any ways to defined such action by using `styled`???

Comment: I would use `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` and set a `State` that contains the style parameters you're looking for. IE `onMouseOver={setHoverState(true)}` -- `onMouseOut={setHoverState(false)}`

Comment: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components

Answer (score 1):

I would set a state then use a conditional to change styles ..  IE

```
const [hoverState, setHoverState] = useState(false);


<MyComponent
   onMouseOver={setHoverState(true)}
   onMouseOut={setHoverState(false)}
   style={hoverState ? {transform: "scale(1.2)",marginRight: "20px",} : ''}
   >
       some images...
</MyComponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `css` and `styled-components`.

Note that the `styled` function is not meant to be called directly, but passed a template literal. Inside the template literal, you can write regular css expressions.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-chihiro-onhh15?file=/src/App.js)

```js
const MyComponent = styled.div`
  transform: scale(1);
  margin-right: 0px;

  :hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
`;
```